# How was Thor revived in Thor (2011)?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, thor

In Thor we see him get killed near the end of the movie by the Destroyer that was sent by Loki.

Yet once he regains the hammer, all his injuries are gone.

The entire fight sequence is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmLcJ6UO5_Y).

- 0:53 his face is badly injured
- Starting at 1:00 we see Jane, Lady Sif, Loki, and the Destroy all seem to believe he is dead
- 1:42 Odin releases the tear
- 2:21 as the hammer flies his arm rises to grasp it
- 2:52 his face is uninjured

So the [Mjolnir](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mjolnir) we've seen in the cinematic universe hasn't demonstrated any healing abilities. However in an alternate story it seems that it does (at at least the transformation it enabled):

> Unfortunately for her, all progress from chemotherapy became lost whenever she used Mjolnir to transform into Thor. Since the magical transformation purged all toxins from Jane's body, it did so to the chemotherapy drugs, but left the cancer behind since it was part of her body.

Now in the scene he did "transform" into Thor, however, Loki and the Destroy's behaviors seem to be strong indicators that Thor actually was dead. I also have a hard time to believe that Odin's tear can bring someone back from so far away.

We know that Thor can be injured while using the hammer due to the events in Age of Ultron and Thor 2.

Comment: We can't actually tell that he is dead, but that is beside the point.  We see more than just his face losing its injuries - he regains his armor for example.  It seems like this relates to Odin's "spell" on him, removing his powers, has been ended.

Comment: @iandotkelly Do you really think Loki would stop unless he was reasonably sure that he desired outcome had been achieved?

Comment: Being unconscious doesn't mean he's dead

Comment: Thor is not the god of Hammers.

Comment: Stormbreaker also heals Thor from near-death

Answer (score 3):

> Now in the scene he did "transform" into Thor, however, Loki and the Destroy's behaviors seem to be strong indicators that Thor actually was dead.

The script ([or at least one version of it](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html)) would seem to indicate that Thor was **almost** dead...

> ```
>     Thor's eyes close, his last breath leaving his lips. The 
>     Destroyer stands over Thor's body, lowers its head towards
>     him. It opens its faceplate, locks it in place, readying to
>     unleash its fiery blast.
> ```

However, this does not *quite* match the action we see in the final movie.

Based on the action we see, it seem likely that Thor **was**, in fact, dead (or at least dead enough for the Destroyer and everyone else to think so) BUT Odin decided that his sacrifice was enough to make Thor *worthy* again and resurrected him.

Whether Odin has this power is undefined but since he is the most powerful of a race of alien space-gods, it doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: If Odin did have the power to bring people back, you think he would have used it on his wife as well

Comment: Mostly dead is the answer then. Just not completely dead.